# What's the percentage of simplified characters in the most common characters?

Tags: traditional-vs-simplified

I've searched in here and elsewhere on the web and couldn't find the answer.

What's the percentage of the most common characters (say, top 5000) that underwent simplification?

Thank you!

Comment: baike.baidu：1986年10月10日重新发表《简化字总表》，刊载在10月15日的《人民日报》（共收2235个简化字）, therefore ２２３５／５０００ would seem to be a reasonable estimate,
note however that there are 6763 characters in  GB２３１２, therefore if all with only one of the 14 simplified 偏旁 are included in the 2235,
one might have to deduct a number of rarely used such simplified ones from 2235 (like names for rare chemical elements), anyhow 2235/6763 might be the percentage of GB2312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_4d3f04b40100ffxk.html
有学者王鼎吉统计：以国家语委、国家教委1988年1月26日联合发布的《现代汉语常用字表》为例，在3500个常用字中，有简化字1116个，占31.9%，即不到三分之一
there are 31.9% character undergo simplification in the most common 3500 characters.